# How was this deck/fence panel built?

Tags: deck, fence

If you zoom in you can see that the posts have has a groove to slide in the boards but I wonder if they guy used spaces or screws to position the horizontal boards

How do you make posts like this? A dado blade or a router? Do these posts resist in time? I am thinking about the water that might widen the grooves

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, Dado Blade, Multiple passes with single blade, Router, Chisel, Specialty Plane to name most of them. Board spacing can be drilled/driven into the posts or boards screws, nails, staples, blocks or pegs. Or, end extensions but usually full height end slats are screwed to the boards & then the whole panel is slid in as 1-piece, a rotated stair balustrade. Or, the boards can just have the centers cut out to leave end legs.

Comment: I see a potential problem there when the grooves take rain water. I think that it might accelerate the aging and the cracking of the wood as the time passes

Comment: I'm sure, but it's actually vastly better than most fences from a water respect, as the boards can be beveled or rounded. Regular fences have much deeper horizontals that retain snow, ice & water, because of very bad lazy design. Attaching the board ends to stainless steel rails in a slightly loose side to side fit would minimize water's rotting ability. If the bottom of the thin slot was done with a Dado then a ramp could remain to kick the water away from the post's bottom. There's always a tweak of improvement.

Comment: I was hopping that this design avoids using metal, screws and nails as the boards can be set using spacers (everything will be supported by one or two boards that will be nailed , one at the bottom , one at the middle, the others can be just slided in) Well I know realize that exposure to water my bow the boards ..so one disadvantage of this design is that you can not use very long boards and you need more posts....

Comment: But, I'm talking about the best hard metal :) In an all wood setup I'd probably opt for dowels in the bottom of each board. Slit the ends, so water can't sit in the grooves. Laterally drill & peg just the top board. Yes, these panels would be best if they were 4' or less wide for this style. However, if you did a full wrap frame with the top & bottom rails beveled then you could double the panel width with a center stretcher. This is what vertical fences do as well, so each board supports each other. This could also be done with pegs instead of nails or screws.